# Is there a way to automate solving for coefficients in multivariable systems of equations?

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to find a way to automate solving for **all** possible numerical values in a large multivariable system of equations. By this I mean equations such as

> k(90)*g(-3)=434

and

> k(47)*g(-5)=237

Essentially I want to solve for variables such as g and k in the context of one another and all the equations (the equations are much more complex - I am simplifying for clarity).

Is this a feasible approach and if so how would I go about achieving this? In addition, is this doable if I want the product value to be within a set number range? For example,

> k(47)*g(-5)= a number from 217-257

If this is also doable, I am eager to hear it.

Apologies if I sound incoherent-- if any clarification is needed feel free to ask. Many thanks in advance.

Edited to add: These equations will all be either linear or quadratic in nature. I am looking for integer solutions preferably, but finding real number solutions would also work.

Comment: There are ways.  The best method depends a lot on what types of equations you have.  Are all of the equations quadratic?  Are you looking for solutions that are integers, or real numbers, or something else?  Please [edit] the question to provide more details.

Comment: Just added an edit for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the equalities from your example:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
90k - 3g & = & 434 \\
47k - 5g & = & 237
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Well, that's just a linear system, and can be solved by Gaussian elimination or other similar technique.

If we look at the inequalities:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
47k - 5g & \le & 257 \\
-47k + 5g & \le & 217 \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

That's a [linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). If you want integer solutions, then this is exactly the integer linear program feasibility problem, which is known to be NP-hard. For rational solutions, this is solvable in polynomial time, but in practice, the simplex method works extremely well.

If you have quadratic equality constraints, then [Quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) isn't quite what you want, because most of the algorithms for that only talk about quadratic objective functions, not equality constraints. Someone else might know better than I do on this point, but you may want to look into something like [cylindrical algebraic decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition), which in theory should work with any polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NP-hard, when you have quadratic constraints.

Solving over the reals: then your problem is an instance of quadratically constrained quadratic programming (QCQP), and you can find a single solution with a [QCQP solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program).  Finding all solutions is challenging.  One standard approach is to find one solution, then add a "blocking constraint" to rule out that one solution and solve again.  For instance, if you have the single solution $x=13$, $y=15$, it might work to add the blocking constraint $(x-13)^2+(y-15)^2 > 0$ to the system of equations, and solve it again.  (This requires the solver to allow "$>$" inequalities.  If it only accepts "$\ge$" inequalities, one possibility is to try picking some small $\epsilon$, and require $\ge \epsilon$ instead of $>0$, but this is a heuristic that is not guaranteed to work.)  There might be better ways.

You could also try [Groebner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).

Solving over the integers: It appears it is undecidable whether there exists any solution over the integers.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616704/14578.  I am not an expert in this area, so I can't independently confirm or refute that statement.

Standard warning: there might be exponentially many solutions, so if you really want to enumerate all solutions, then enumerating all of them can take exponential time in the worst case.

Related: [Does Quadratically-Constrainted Quadratic Programming get easier if all constraints are equalities?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/102775/755), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations, [Is deciding solvability of systems of quadratic equations with integer coefficients over the reals in NP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/127282/755), https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084636/14578, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1366528/14578.